# Log an HTTP Header in Apache2 Access Logs

Tags: apache, logging, http-headers

I have a website running behind Cloudflare, which is a reverse-proxy. This means that I only ever get one or two IP addresses in my access logs.

However, Cloudflare does provide the visitor IP address in the request headers, which I assume I can log instead of the standard one in an access log.

I know how to use `CustomLog`, but is there a way to save an HTTP header in an Apache access log?

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Aye - have a look at the docs - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html  specifically the entry for

```
%{Foobar}i
```

Which will net you:

> The contents of Foobar: header line(s) in the request sent to the
>   server. Changes made by other modules (e.g. mod_headers) affect this.
>   If you're interested in what the request header was prior to when most
>   modules would have modified it, use mod_setenvif to copy the header
>   into an internal environment variable and log that value with the
>   %{VARNAME}e described above.

So one would usually add some entry like "... %{X-Forwarded-For-IP}i to the CustomLog entry.

Replace 'X-Forwarded-For-IP' to whateever your cloudflare service gets you (which usually is something like ''"CF-Connecting-IP"''); e.g.

```
 LogFormat "%v %{CF-Connecting-IP}i (via cloudflare:%h) %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" cloudflare
 CustomLog "|rotatelog.. etc" cloudflare
```

With regard to the 'transferlog' -- see the note near TransferLog Directive -- that it picks up the most recent defined version.

Dw.